# Como guardar los registros de una tabla dinámica en html y mostrarlos utilizando Javascript para validar los datos

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla en la que añado o elimino mediante botones las filas con sus correspondientes campos, conformando así una matriz de "i" filas x "j" columnas.  Todos los inputs del formulario son procesados como un array y guardados en una B.D tal cual sin validarlos. 
El problema lo tengo cuando quiero validarlos antes de enviarlos a la B.D , que lo hago llamando a la función correspondiente en JavaScript. El código solo me llega a mostrar el primer registro de la tabla esto es, el bucle que recorre el array, vuelve a mostrar siempre los datos de la primera fila de la tabla y no encuentro el motivo del por qué el resto de filas no. Les estaría muy agradecido me echaran una mano. Gracias.

EL FORMULARIO CON LA TABLA

```js
function agregarFila(){
document.getElementById("tablainvitados").insertRow(-1).innerHTML =
'<td><input id="nomape_nosocio"  type=text name=nomape_nosocio[]/></td><td><input id="dni_nosocio"  type=text  name=dni_nosocio[]/></td>';
}

function eliminarFila(){
  var table = document.getElementById("tablainvitados");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  //console.log(rowCount);
  
  if(rowCount <= 1)
    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado'); 
  else
    table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
                       }



function pregunta_Validar_Campos(){
var aArray= [document.getElementById('nomape_nosocio').value,document.getElementById('dni_nosocio').value];

 var table = document.getElementById("tablainvitados");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;


 // Recorremos todas las filas y columnas de la tabla con el objetivo de recuperar y validar todos los campos introducidos en la tabla 
         for (var i = 0; i < rowCount-1; i++) {
   for (var j= 0; j < aArray.length; j++) {
                
    document.write( "El valor de la posición [" + i+ "][" +j+ "] es [" +aArray[j] + "]<br/>" );  // aqui solo testea los valores recibidos llegando solo los campos de la primera fila
                                             }
                                              }

     if (confirm('Los datos serán guardados en la Base de Datos. ¿Estás seguro de realizar esta acción?'))
    {document.Actualizar.submit() } 
                                   }
```

```html
<form name="Actualizar" action="" method="POST">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table border="1" class="table" id="tablainvitados">
      <thead class="thead-dark">

             
        <tr>
                <th>Nombre y Apellidos</th>
    <th>NIF</th>
                                   
        </tr>
  
  
  
<td><input id="nomape_nosocio" type=text  name=nomape_nosocio[] value="" /></td>

<td><input id="dni_nosocio" type=text name=dni_nosocio[] value=""/></td>

      </tr>
      
  
      </thead>
      
    

</table>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" onclick="agregarFila()">Agregar Fila</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-2" onclick="eliminarFila()">Eliminar Fila</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="pregunta_Validar_Campos()">Actualizar Datos</button>



 </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

El error se debe en parte a que estás duplicando IDs. Cada vez que creas una fila le das los mismos IDs a los campos (los mismos que en la primera fila). Entonces al seleccionar por ID sólo se va a devolver el primero que se encuentre, que es el problema que estás viendo.

Otro problema que se presenta es cómo se está generando la tabla de resultados, que siempre va a tener un único valor en lugar de todos los valores del formulario, porque sólo estás creando un array con dos valores: los de la primera fila.

Por último, un tercer problema es cómo se muestran los datos. Parece que quieres tener un array bidimensional donde el primer elemento será un array con nombres y el segundo elemento será un array con los DNIs. Independientemente de cómo mejor o peor sea esa manera de organizar el contenido (personalmente no optaría por ella), seguramente querrías tener un índice doble `aArray[i][j]` en lugar de un único índice `aArray[j]`.

Mi recomendación:

- No dupliques IDs: añade clases o `name` en su lugar.
- Usa esas clases para seleccionar los valores y guardarlos en un array bidimensional
- Muestra los datos basándote en cada una de las filas.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando: (con comentarios)

```js
function agregarFila() {
  // añade clases y no IDs duplicados
  document.getElementById("tablainvitados").insertRow(-1).innerHTML =
    '<td><input id="nomape_nosocio" class="nomape_nosocio"  type=text name=nomape_nosocio[]/></td><td><input id="dni_nosocio"  type=text class="dni_nosocio" name=dni_nosocio[]/></td>';
}

function eliminarFila() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tablainvitados");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  if (rowCount <= 1)
    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado');
  else
    table.deleteRow(rowCount - 1);
}



function pregunta_Validar_Campos() {

  // selecciona TODOS los campos por clase
  const nomapes = document.querySelectorAll(".nomape_nosocio");
  const dnis = document.querySelectorAll(".dni_nosocio");
  
  // los convertimos a un array bidimensional
  // el primer elemento sera un array con los nombres
  // el segundo elemento sera un array con los dnis
  aArray = [
    [...nomapes].map(el => el.value),
    [...dnis].map(el => el.value)
  ];
  
  var table = document.getElementById("tablainvitados");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < aArray.length; j++) {

      // además de la columna, también quieres leer la fila! aArray[j][i] en lugar de aArray[j]
      document.write("El valor de la posición [" + i + "][" + j + "] es [" + aArray[j][i] + "]<br/>");
    }
  }

  if (confirm('Los datos serán guardados en la Base de Datos. ¿Estás seguro de realizar esta acción?')) {
    document.Actualizar.submit()
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="Actualizar" action="" method="POST">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <table border="1" class="table" id="tablainvitados">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th>Nombre y Apellidos</th>
            <th>NIF</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <!-- cambia los IDs por clases -->
            <td><input class="nomape_nosocio"  type=text name=nomape_nosocio[] value="" /></td>
            <td><input class="dni_nosocio" type=text name=dni_nosocio[] value="" /></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" onclick="agregarFila()">Agregar Fila</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-2" onclick="eliminarFila()">Eliminar Fila</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="pregunta_Validar_Campos()">Actualizar Datos</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

Esta parte del código puedes ser un poco confusa:

```
const nomapes = document.querySelectorAll(".nomape_nosocio");
const dnis = document.querySelectorAll(".dni_nosocio");

aArray = [
  [...nomapes].map(el => el.value),
  [...dnis].map(el => el.value)
];
```

Lo que se está haciendo es seleccionar los diferentes elementos con clase `.nomape_nosocio` y `.dni_nosocio` y con [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) lo que hago es generar un nuevo array para quedarme sólo con los valores. Desafortunadamente, `map` no funciona directamente con el resultado de `querySelectorAll` y por eso hago el `[...variable]` (uso la [sintáxis spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) para generar un array con el que operar.

Sé que el párrafo de arriba puede ser algo confuso. Para hacerlo más sencillo, el código de arriba es equivalente a hacer lo siguiente:

```
var nomapes = document.querySelectorAll(".nomape_nosocio");
var dnis = document.querySelectorAll(".dni_nosocio");

var nomapesValores = [];
for (var x = 0; x < nomapes.length; x++) {
  nomapesValores.push( nomapes[x].value );
}

var dnisValores = [];
for (var x = 0; x < dnis.length; x++) {
  dnisValores.push( dnis[x].value );
}

var aArray = [ nomapesValores, dnisValores ];
```

Espero que así se vea más claro.

Comment: Sé que la parte del `map` es un poco confusa. Dime si no se entiende bien y lo intento editar para explicarme mejor.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro por contestar. Efectivamente era la idea que tenia aunque no entiendo muy bien esto aArray = [
    [...nomapes].map(el => el.value),
    [...dnis].map(el => el.value)
  ];

Comment: Gracias Alvaro. ¿Podrías explicarme lo del map ?. Es la primera vez que lo veo. He ejecutado el codigo en el navegador y algo no le gusta. El error que arroja es: }
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: (var)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 66,
  "colno": 9
}.   Es algo de un simbolo que no reconoce . Voy a ir probando y luego posteo. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: @MAC he editado la respuesta para añadir una descripción. Espero no confundir las cosas  más :-/

Comment: He probado las dos formas sugeridas y la que ha funcionado 100% , ajustando un poco mi código , es la segunda. La primera, aunque con menos linea de código no me ha funcionado, arrojaba el error descrito anteriormente, puede ser algún problema de la función .map con el navegador Chrome , no he probado con otros navegadores. Cierro el hilo y posteo el codigo completo por si alguien le sirve.

Comment: Funciona bien, pero ahora como almaceno los valores del arreglo en la base de datos?

Comment: @JesusAbano eso sería para una nueva pregunta

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÓN A LA PREGUNTA:  " Guardar los registros de una tabla dinámica y mostrarlos para su validación con JavaScripts "  COMPROBADO FUNCIONANDO AL 100%.

```js
function agregarFila(){
document.getElementById("tablainvitados").insertRow(-1).innerHTML =
 '<td><input id="nomape_nosocio" class="nomape_nosocio"  type=text name=nomape_nosocio[]/></td><td><input id="dni_nosocio"  type=text class="dni_nosocio" name=dni_nosocio[]/></td>';
}

function eliminarFila(){
  var table = document.getElementById("tablainvitados");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  //console.log(rowCount);
  
  if(rowCount <= 1)
    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado'); 
  else
    table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
                       }

function pregunta_Validar_Campos(){

// selecciona TODOS los campos de la tabla por clase
 var nomapes = document.querySelectorAll(".nomape_nosocio");
    var dnis = document.querySelectorAll(".dni_nosocio");

// Cada campo es convertido a un array bidimensional
var nomapesValores = [];
for (var x = 0; x < nomapes.length; x++) {
  nomapesValores.push( nomapes[x].value );
}

var dnisValores = [];
for (var x = 0; x < dnis.length; x++) {
  dnisValores.push( dnis[x].value );
}
// Nuevo array bidimensional del conjunto de campos creados 
        var aArray = [ nomapesValores, dnisValores ];
// Cuenta el numero de filas introducidas en la tabla
        var table = document.getElementById("tablainvitados");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
// Recorremos aArray y recuperamos los datos de la tabla  
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < aArray.length; j++) {

     
      document.write("El valor de la posición [" + i + "][" + j + "] es [" + aArray[j][i] + "]<br/>");
    }
  }

  if (confirm('Los datos serán guardados en la Base de Datos. ¿Estás seguro de realizar esta acción?'))
     {document.Actualizar.submit()}
  
}
```

```html
<form name="Actualizar" action="" method="POST">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table border="1" class="table" id="tablainvitados">
      <thead class="thead-dark">

             
        <tr>
                <th>Nombre y Apellidos</th>
    <th>NIF</th>
                                   
        </tr>
  
      <tr> 
 // utilizar o añadir input por class 
<td><input  id="nomape_nosocio"  class="nomape_nosocio" type=text  name=nomape_nosocio[] value="" /></td>

<td><input id="dni_nosocio" class="dni_nosocio" type=text name=dni_nosocio[] value=""/></td>

      </tr>
      
  
      </thead>
      
    

</table>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" onclick="agregarFila()">Agregar Fila</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-2" onclick="eliminarFila()">Eliminar Fila</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="pregunta_Validar_Campos()">Actualizar Datos</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```